# AppleScript Error when Adding Event to Calendar from Python: "Failed to save event"

Tags: python, macos, calendar, applescript

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a Python script that uses AppleScript to add events to my Calendar on macOS. However, I'm encountering a persistent error related to the event end date. Despite various attempts to troubleshoot, I haven't been able to resolve it. Below is the relevant part of my code and the error I'm facing.

```
import subprocess

def addEventToCalendar(start, end, title):
    applescript = f"""
        tell application "Calendar"
            set newEvent to make new event at end of events of calendar "Antoine M"
            set start date of newEvent to date "{start}"
            set end date of newEvent to date "{end}"
            set description of newEvent to "{title}"
        end tell
    """
    subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', applescript], check=True)

# Example usage
addEventToCalendar("2023-11-29T09:00:00", "2023-11-29T10:00:00", "Sample Meeting")
```

## Error:

```
65:120: execution error: Error in Calendar: Failed to save event [] with error [{
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Aucune date de fin n’a été définie."; //No end date is defined
}] (-10025)
```

## Additional Information:

There seems to be limited documentation and examples regarding the use of AppleScript for Calendar events via Python.
The start date seems to be processed correctly, but the issue persists with the end date.
Any insights or solutions to why the Calendar is not recognizing the end date would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

## Attempts to Resolve:

I've tried modifying the date formats.
Ensured that the error is not due to the format itself, as a different error message appears when the format is incorrect.

Comment: do you have problem when you try to set it directly without using `python`? Did you check `print( applescript )` to see what you really send?

Comment: I tried in the Apple native script editor and the issue is the same.
I also tried to print applescript and it's all good.

Comment: If `Apple native script editor` has the same problem then you have wrong text. Maybe it needs different text `end date `